# PublicClientApplication ExecuteAsync

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms. The login page has a button that opens Microsoft sign in. After successful sign in, I want to redirect to Home Page.

This code never hits the if statement, so I never get a token. What I am doing wrong?

```
    private async Task OnSignInAsync()
    {
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult;

        authenticationResult = await App.PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(App.Scopes).WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.CurrentActivity).WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true).ExecuteAsync();

        if (authenticationResult != null)
        {
            var token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(HomePage));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you share sample code to repro this issue via github ?

Comment: public static Activity CurrentActivity;
        public static IPublicClientApplication PublicClientApplication;
        public static string[] Scopes = { "User.Read" };

        public App(Activity _CurrentActivity)
        {
            CurrentActivity = _CurrentActivity;

            PublicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                .WithRedirectUri(uri)
                .Build();
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new AppShell();
        }

Comment: private async Task OnSignInAsync()
        {
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await App.PublicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(App.Scopes).WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.CurrentActivity).WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true).ExecuteAsync();

            if (authenticationResult != null)
            {
                var token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
                //await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(HomePage));
            }
        }